# How do I combine Playframework evolutions with Slick Tables autogeneration?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, slick-3.0

Playframework allows me to use evolution SQL scripts to keep my database up-to-date. (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Evolutions) Slick allows me to run a generation program that reads my database structure and creates table and row objects. (http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.0/code-generation.html)

I really like both of these tools: is there a good way to combine them? If the is no way to combine them, what should I replace the evolution scripts with?

Answer (score 1):

The solution I ended up with:

- I write new SQL as evolution scripts.
- I copy paste the SQL from the evolution script to a psql console to test it on my local postgresql db.
- With my local database updated, I run the Slick code generator to get an up to date Tables.scala.
- I revert the database changes from my local database with the down script in the evolution (or just by hand).

The next time I run my application, the evolution runs and updates my db. This works pretty well, now that I am used to the process.